# Extract src from the description of rss in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss

I have a RSS description as follows:

> 'description: <a href="http://www.afaqs.com/news/story/50219_Management-changes-at-Disney-Vijay-Subramaniam-quits-Abhishek-Maheshwari-to-head-Disney-Media"><img src="http://www.afaqs.com/all/news/images/news_story_grfx/2017/50219_1_home_small.jpg" alt=" " hspace="5" align="left" width="59" height="59" border="0"/></a> The network has also elevated Sanjeet Mehta as head of Disney Consumer Products.'

i have to extract img src from this in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this approach:

1. Create a div element with an ID.
2. In your javascript code, set InnerHTML value to your div with the value of description.
3. Use querySelectorAll and get the source of the image.

Example:

```js
var description = 'description: <a href="http: //www.afaqs.com/news/story/50219_Management-changes-at-Disney-Vijay-Subramaniam-quits-Abhishek-Maheshwari-to-head-Disney-Media"><img src="http://www.afaqs.com/all/news/images/news_story_grfx/2017/50219_1_home_small.jpg" alt=" " hspace="5" align="left" width="59" height="59" border="0"/></a> The network has also elevated Sanjeet Mehta as head of Disney Consumer Products.';

// Set InnerHTML values:
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = description;

// Get src:
var mySrcValue = document.querySelectorAll('#myDiv > a > img')[0].src;

// Show src value:
document.getElementById('myResult').innerHTML = "<b>" + mySrcValue + "</b>";
```

```html
<span>This is your div:</span>
<br />
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<br/>
<br/>
<span>IMG SRC Result is:</span>
<div id="myResult"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will surely try that

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jquery to do this, javascript is enough.
You can extract the src attribute with a one line code (split and regex) :

```
var result = description.split('img')[1].split('alt')[0].match( /"(.*?)"/ )[1];
```

```js
var description = 'description: <a href="http: //www.afaqs.com/news/story/50219_Management-changes-at-Disney-Vijay-Subramaniam-quits-Abhishek-Maheshwari-to-head-Disney-Media"><img src="http://www.afaqs.com/all/news/images/news_story_grfx/2017/50219_1_home_small.jpg" alt=" " hspace="5" align="left" width="59" height="59" border="0"/></a> The network has also elevated Sanjeet Mehta as head of Disney Consumer Products.';

result.innerHTML = description.split('img')[1].split('alt')[0].match( /"(.*?)"/ )[1];
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```